# Removing large files from git index and synchronising all branches

Tags: git, indexing

After removing indexes with git filter-branch, a colleague's push brings the old indexes back.

I run a bitbucket repo and it grew to over 2GB in size, where it becomes read only. In order to recover the situation they recommend resetting to a previous commit and cleaning my index with git filter branch. Which I did, with success. Having done this, and pruned, my local size size-pack (git count-objects) dropped to 300MB. However bitbucket only dropped to 1.2GB, I don't understand the difference, but there is a bigger problem.

When my colleague, who also uses that branch, pushed more changes, the size jumped back up to over 2GB. Obviously they still had the indexes locally (though they had done a git pull first).

The commands I ran were ...

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --ignore-unmatch NAME_OF_DIRECTORY_I_DONT_WANT_ANYMORE' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Repeated for all relevant directories, and then:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

git gc --prune=now --aggressive

git push --all --force
```

1.) I don't understand what happened, can anyone enlighten me?

2.) When I fix the situation again by git filter-branch, pruning etc, and pushing to the server, how can I ensure that my colleague gets these changes also? So we don't continually repeat the cycle?

Comment: The *index* is a (temporary) data structure that your Git uses to keep track of your (temporary) work-tree contents, and to build new commits. It is not part of any repository, hence the word "temporary" here. The large files are *in* the commits, frozen there forever. They cannot be changed. At best, you can copy the old commits (that have these large files) to new-and-improved commits (that don't). That's what `git filter-branch` does. The old commits continue to exist, and any time you connect your Git to a Git that has and is still using the old commits, your Git gets them from their Git.

Comment: What this implies is that *everyone* who has *any* pre-filtering copy (clone) of a filtered Git repository must throw it away, or at least, seal it off as if it were radioactive, touching it only with long poles. Otherwise the old commits will keep coming back, like some sort of alien virus.

Answer (score 0):

The most drastic way is : have them start from a fresh git clone.

If they need to keep some local branches : one basic way is to copy files from their old clone to their new clone ; another way is to add the old repo as a remote of the new clone, then fetch + rebase.

One way to avoid the reappearance of one of the folders you deleted is to add a pre-receive hook on your git server which will reject any commit that contains one of the forbidden folders, or a pre-push hook on the repo of your colleagues